# Rounded border on UIButton has disappeared

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I had a rounded UIButton in a custom table view cell initialized via a `XIB`, and it was working fine. I just noticed that the border, a circular pink border, now doesn't appear. I tried adding some code to also set the property in the `awakeFromNib` function, but this also didn't do the trick.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setupProfileView];
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.97f alpha:1.0f];
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    _initialLabel.layer.cornerRadius = _initialLabel.frame.size.width/2;
    _initialLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    _initialLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:223.0/255.0 green:158.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
    NSLog(@"on profile table view cell border width is %f and radius is %f and color is %@", _initialLabel.layer.cornerRadius, _initialLabel.layer.borderWidth, _initialLabel.layer.borderColor);
}
```

The above prints out what I would expect (the correct color + radius + width), but it doesn't show in the view. It's the only reference in code to `_initialLabel`, so it's not getting set somewhere else in code.

Has anyone run into this and know a fix? Any ideas how to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Is the button outlet called _initialLabel? If so, that's a very confusing name. (I would expect an outlet with that name to be a UILabel, not a button.) Are you sure the button is visible? Try changing some other property like the background color to make sure you are working with the field you think you are.

Comment: If _initialLabel indeed is a button, which I agree with @DuncanC seems unlikely, it is worth checking that type is set to custom and not system.

Comment: try setting `self.initialLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;` (also, it's best to use `self.` instead of accessing the ivar directly since you're outside of a setter or getter)