# UICollectionViewCell border disappears when layer.borderColor is set

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, border, uicollectionviewcell, calayer

I'm trying to add a thin, colored border to a `@IBDesignable UICollectionViewCell` prototype. In the storyboard, I've set the `layer.cornerRadius`, `layer.masksToBounds`, and `layer.borderWidth` user-defined properties, and the border shows up as expected.

[image]

However, if I also set a custom `layer.borderColor`, the whole border, radius, and mask disappear from the storyboard. In the Simulator, the corner radius (and mask, presumably) appear, but the border doesn't.

[image]

I've also tried setting them programmatically, but as [this year-old, unanswered StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405156/rounded-border-on-uibutton-has-disappeared) shows, that doesn't work, either.

Here's the code for the cell, as requested:

```
@IBDesignable open class ReleaseSpineCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    public var masterRelease: MasterRelease? {
        didSet {
            artistName = masterRelease?.artistName
            title = masterRelease?.title
            catalogNumber = "none"
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var artistName: String? {
        didSet {
            artistLabel?.text = artistName
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var title: String? {
        didSet {
            titleLabel?.text = title
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var catalogNumber: String? {
        didSet {
            catalogLabel?.text = catalogNumber
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet private weak var artistLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet private weak var titleLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet private weak var catalogLabel: UILabel?

}
```

And the relevant part of the `UICollectionViewController`'s `dataSource`:

```
class CollectionModel: FetchedResultsCollectionModel {

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "spineCell", for: indexPath) as! ReleaseSpineCell
        cell.masterRelease = fetchedResultsController?.fetchedObjects?[indexPath.row] as? MasterRelease

        return cell
    }
}
```

`FetchedResultsCollectionModel` is a custom collection view data source and delegate that's backed by an `NSFetchedResultsController`, and `MasterRelease` is the managed object. I try to keep this stuff as simple as possible.

Comment: Can you post your code for your custom Cell?

Comment: Sure, but it's just a handful of `IBOutlet`s; no interesting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are using `Boolean` Value for `layer.borderColor` you must to use `Color` instead. But anyway this don't work because for `layer.borderColor` you need a `cgColor` so I think you need define a @IBInspectable var for borderColor and do this in code

```
@IBDesignable open class ReleaseSpineCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    public var masterRelease: MasterRelease? {
        didSet {
            artistName = masterRelease?.artistName
            title = masterRelease?.title
            catalogNumber = "none"
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var artistName: String? {
        didSet {
            artistLabel?.text = artistName
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var title: String? {
        didSet {
            titleLabel?.text = title
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var catalogNumber: String? {
        didSet {
            catalogLabel?.text = catalogNumber
        }
    }

    //added this inspectable property
    @IBInspectable public var borderColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderColor = borderColor!.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet private weak var artistLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet private weak var titleLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet private weak var catalogLabel: UILabel?

}
```

**Then you will be able to do this in storyboard**

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah, good call on the `Boolean` type I had for the `layer.borderColor`. However, I just uploaded the wrong screenshot--I *did* have it set to be a `Color`. When `Color` is specified as the type in a user-defined attribute, IB knows that it's really a `CGColor`, so I don't think that that's the problem. But I can see from your example that you got it to work, so I'm doing something else wrong. What Xcode version are you using? I'm on 9 beta 4.

Comment: @NRitH did you try adding the borderColor as an inspectable property as I said in my answer?, must work, anyway Iam using Xcode 8.3.2

Comment: Yes, it works if I add an inspectable property like you suggested. I know that I've had this work on other projects; I'm going to chalk it up to a bug in Xcode 9 beta 4.

Comment: @NRitH In Xcode 8.3.2 don't work setting as direct property of layer.borderColor, so if you fin the way please let me know I want to learn it

Comment: Hmm. Now you're making me doubt myself...I'll have to dig through old projects.